# Accessing image array elements for marker icons

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to have different icons for each of my markers which are in an array. I have simply added the icon path (as a string) on the end of my locations array.
I am not sure I am accessing the icons correctly within my 'marker' for loop.

I am getting this error in the console when I run:

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property
```

Which I think is telling me that the path is incorrect/not there, this is correct though, so I believe it's not accessing the array correctly. 

How should I be doing this? Or should the icons be in a separate array themselves?

**Edit:** The icons correctly load if I have them in a separate array, however I would like to know if I can use the one multidimensional array rather than have a multidimensional array and another standard array.

```
function initialize() {

var locations = [
     ['Title A', 3.180967,101.715546, 1, '/images/icons/letter_a.png'],
     ['Title B', 3.200848,101.616669, 2,'/images/icons/letter_b.png'],
     ['Title C', 3.147372,101.597443, 3,'/images/icons/letter_c.png'],
     ['Title D', 3.19125,101.710052, 4, '/images/icons/letter_d.png']
];



  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(3.182362,101.044922);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
        icon: locations[i][3]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
         return function() {
             infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
    })(marker, i));

  }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your array position wrong `icon: locations[i][3]` is a numeric value `icon: locations[i][4]` is the reference for the icon URL, change this line and you'll be there :)

Comment: Ah yes, I seem to have miscounted!